# Перебор элементов Map<> на соответствие с множеством Set<> в JAVA

Tags: java, коллекции, map

Есть метод с типом возвращаемого значения `Map<OptionDescription, String>`, а именно вот такой `private Map<OptionDescription, String> verifyLocalOptions(Set<OptionDescription> localAvailable, Set<OptionDescription> localMandatory, Map<String, String> local)`.Задача, в которой я запутался состоит в том, чтобы  - 1.Обойти `Map<String, String> local`и проверить, что все значения совпадают со значениями из `Set<OptionDescription> localAvailable`, но кол-во не обязательно совпадает и, 2.Обойти `Set<OptionDescription> localMandatory`и проверить, что все из обязательных значений находятся в `Map<String, String> local`. Со вторым пунктом я справился, а вот с первым - запутался. Помогите, кто может.) Вот код, который получился:

```
private Map<OptionDescription, String> verifyLocalOptions(Set<OptionDescription> localAvailable, Set<OptionDescription> localMandatory, Map<String, String> local) {

    Map<OptionDescription, String> verifyLocal = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : local.entrySet()) {
        String value = entry.getValue();

        for (OptionDescription optionDescription : localMandatory) {
            boolean containsLongKey = local.containsKey(optionDescription.getOption());
            boolean containsShortKey = local.containsKey(optionDescription.getShortOptionName());
            if (!containsLongKey && !containsShortKey) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Local options" + " " + "'" + optionDescription.getOption() + "'"
                        + " or " + "'" + optionDescription.getShortOptionName() + "'" + " is missing!");
            }
            value = containsLongKey ? local.get(optionDescription.getOption()) : local.get(optionDescription.getShortOptionName());
            verifyLocal.put(optionDescription, value);
        }
    }
    return verifyLocal;
}
```

OptionDescription:

```
public enum OptionDescription {
FILE("file", "file", "file name"),
NAME("name", "n", "name of person"),
SURNAME("surname", "s", "surname of person"),
AGE("age", "a", "age of person"),
EMAIL("email", "e", "person email address"),
FROM("from", "from", "what needs to be replaced"),
TO("to", "to", "what will be replaced"),
ID("id", "id", "ID of person");

private final String option;
private final String shortOptionName;
private final String description;

OptionDescription(String option, String shortOptionName, String description) {
    this.option = option;
    this.shortOptionName = shortOptionName;
    this.description = description;

}

public String getOption() {
    return option;
}

public String getShortOptionName() {
    return shortOptionName;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\nOption: " + getOption() + "\nDescription: " + getDescription();
}}
```

Comment: Вы сравниваете String и OptionDescription вот здесь: local.containsKey(optionDescription.getOption()); А что за класс OptionDescription? Его точно можно сравнивать со строкой?

Comment: @Vladimir Yarovoy OptionDescription - это перечисление(enum). Сравнивать со строкой можно. Сейчас я это перечисление добавлю, чтобы видно было, что сравниваем.

Comment: Не делайте вложенные циклы. Пройдите сначала в цикле по local, по примеру, как я написал в своем ответе. Потом аналогично пройдите циклом по localMandatory. И после этих двух проверок, либо бросьте Exception, либо делайте то, что нужно дальше.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

    boolean allPositionsExistInSet = true;

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :map.entrySet()) {
        if (!set.contains(entry.getKey())) {
            allPositionsExistInSet = false;
        }
    }
```